# Solving $y=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, infinite-product

There is the trivial $y=0$, but beyond that, could there be further solutions for $y$ in terms of $x$ such that

$$y=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}\mbox{ pointwise}$$

? I posed this problem to myself, so I have no idea. I began with:
$$\ln(y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}\right)\mbox{ pointwise}$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^{(n+1)}(x)}{y^{(n)}(x)}\mbox{ pointwise}$$
And I've fiddled with various manipulations, but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Integral? I'm not sure that word means what you think it means.

Comment: I want to find an equation for y in terms of x only. I've clarified, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Perhaps the first thing you should try to make sense of, besides the fact of asking yourself such horrible questions, is what **exactly** do you mean by the infinite product of functions...? If it were in some given value of each derivative function $\;\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}\;$  then we could talk of an infinite product of numbers, which could or not converge (perhaps most probably the former), but just functions? Like that?

Comment: This is the problem of course. You can't tell if the series converges until you actually have a function in question. But how can one **prove** that there are no functions that do in fact, converge? I have no idea, and yes, it is a stupid question, feel free to not waste your time on it.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall what I think Timbuc means is that you should precise if you're asking for punctual convergence in the infinite product or some other type of convergence (eg local uniform)

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki okay thanks. I definitely want punctual convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If:

$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{y^{(n+1)}(x)}{y^{(n)}(x)}$$

Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{y^{(n+1)}(x)}{y^{(n)}(x)} = 0$. It follows that, for $n$ large enough, you have $y^{(n+1)}(x) < \frac{1}{2} y^{(n)}(x)$. If this is the case:

$$y(x) = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}y^{(n)}(x) = 0$$

Meaning that $y = 0$. This is not quite a complete solution, since there are potential issues with taking the natural log of non-positive numbers and of moving the derivative past the sum (as you did in the top post). But I think you should be able to fill in the gaps.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the problems of taking the derivative past the sum? I don't want to make such errors in the future.